# Call RESTful API in Apache Flink job main class caused unable to run the job

Tags: java, apache-flink

We have an Apache Flink job need to initial some data by calling external restful API in main class, and then use them in the operators, but when we start the job by Apache Flink admin UI, we got below error, any suggestion will be appreciated.

- I am thinking if we cannot call external API in main class of Apache Flink
  job but need to do it in the `open()` function of operators? but this
  not make sense from design perspective.
- It works well when I debug in may local environment, but fail in the remote Apache Flink cluster.

```java
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not execute application. 
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(JarRunHandler.java:108) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702) ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap 
at   CmpxxService.java:94) 
at (TxxtChooser.java:126) 
at initializeInfo(xxService.java:94) 
at .main(PosJob.java:293) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) 
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) 
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) 
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84) 
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70) 
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:102) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap 
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) 
at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:64) 
at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:74) 
at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:48) 
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ... 21 more
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what you are trying to configure in your operators using an external API?

Comment: Hi @GerardGarcia, thanks for your reply, it fixed on my side. It is because that we use 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' to call RESTful API in the Apache Flink, but not add related package, although it works on local env, but it failed on Flink cluster side without the spring env.
At last we use the native 'java.net.HttpURLConnection' to call the RESTfull API